# Unable to play video in Wowza GoCoder's PlayerActivity

Tags: java, android-fragments, wowza

I keep getting an an error when trying to call WowZa GoCoder SDK's PlayerActivity and I am unable to understand the cause. The error appears when mStreamPlayerView.play(mStreamPlayerConfig, statusCallback) is called. Would really appreciate help on where i am going wrong

vodFragment.java

```
public class vodFragment extends Fragment {


    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    ListView videoView;
    ArrayList <Vidoes> videoList;
    private static String value;
    String videoName;

    String url = "http://192.168.43.149/twende/channelVOD.php";

    public vodFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (getActivity().getActionBar() != null) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(value);
        }


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vod_list, container, false);
        videoView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        videoList = new ArrayList<Vidoes>();
        JSONObject channelInfo = new JSONObject();
        try {
            channelInfo.put("channelName", value);
            channelInfo.put("channelOwner", "dan");

            postJSONObject(url,channelInfo);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return view;
    }

    public static void setChannel(String channel){
       value = channel;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public void postJSONObject(final String myurl, final JSONObject parameters) {

        class postJSONObject extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);

                try {

                    loadIntoVodView(s);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                try {
                    StringBuffer response = null;
                    URL url = new URL(myurl);
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(parameters.toString());
                    writer.close();
                    out.close();
                    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    System.out.println("responseCode" + responseCode);
                    switch (responseCode) {
                        case 200:
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                            String inputLine;
                            response = new StringBuffer();
                            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                response.append(inputLine);
                            }
                            in.close();
                            return response.toString();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (conn != null) {
                        try {
                            conn.disconnect();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;

            }
        }

        postJSONObject postJSONObject = new postJSONObject();
        postJSONObject.execute();
    }

    private void loadIntoVodView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        final String[]  videos = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            videos[i] = removeExtension(obj.getString("title"));

            Vidoes vidoe = new Vidoes();

            vidoe.setTitle(videos[i]);

            videoList.add(vidoe);
        }

        VideoListAdapter adapter = new VideoListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.vodparsedata, videoList);
        videoView.setAdapter(adapter);



        videoView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int position, long arg3) {

                videoName = Arrays.asList(videos).get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerActivity.class);
                String message = videoName+".mp4";
                intent.putExtra("videoName", message);
                startActivity(intent);

                System.out.println("arr: " + Arrays.asList(videos).get(position));


            }


        });
    }

    public static String removeExtension(String fileName) {

        if (fileName.indexOf(".") > 0) {

            return fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));

        } else {

            return fileName;

        }



    }

}
```

PlayerActivity.java

```
public class PlayerActivity extends GoCoderSDKActivityBase {
    final private static String TAG = PlayerActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    String videoName;

    private WOWZPlayerView mStreamPlayerView = null;
    private WOWZPlayerConfig mStreamPlayerConfig = new WOWZPlayerConfig();


    private MultiStateButton    mBtnPlayStream   = null;
    private MultiStateButton    mBtnSettings     = null;
    private MultiStateButton    mBtnMic          = null;
    private MultiStateButton    mBtnScale        = null;
    private SeekBar             mSeekVolume      = null;
    private ProgressDialog      mBufferingDialog = null;

    private StatusView        mStatusView       = null;
    private TextView          mHelp             = null;
    private TimerView         mTimerView        = null;
    private ImageButton       mStreamMetadata   = null;
    private boolean           mUseHLSPlayback   = false;
    private WOWZPlayerView.PacketThresholdChangeListener packetChangeListener = null;
    private VolumeChangeObserver mVolumeSettingChangeObserver = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stream_player);

        mRequiredPermissions = new String[]{};

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras == null) {
                videoName= null;
            } else {
                videoName= extras.getString("videoName");
            }
        } else {
            videoName= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("videoName");
        }

        System.out.print(videoName);

        mStreamPlayerConfig.setIsPlayback(true);
        mStreamPlayerConfig.setHostAddress("192.168.43.149");
        mStreamPlayerConfig.setApplicationName("Dark Souls 2 Channel");
        mStreamPlayerConfig.setStreamName(videoName);
        mStreamPlayerConfig.setPortNumber(1935);

        mStreamPlayerView = (WOWZPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.vwStreamPlayer);

        mBtnPlayStream = (MultiStateButton) findViewById(R.id.ic_play_stream);
        mBtnSettings = (MultiStateButton) findViewById(R.id.ic_settings);
        mBtnMic = (MultiStateButton) findViewById(R.id.ic_mic);
        mBtnScale = (MultiStateButton) findViewById(R.id.ic_scale);

        mTimerView = (TimerView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimer);
        mStatusView = (StatusView) findViewById(R.id.statusView);
        mStreamMetadata = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnStreamInfo);
        mHelp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.streamPlayerHelp);

        mSeekVolume = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb_volume);

        WOWZStatusCallback statusCallback = new StatusCallback();
        mStreamPlayerView.play(mStreamPlayerConfig, statusCallback);


        mTimerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mStreamPlayerView.play(mStreamPlayerConfig, statusCallback);




        if (sGoCoderSDK != null) {

            /*
            Packet change listener setup
             */
            final PlayerActivity activity = this;
            packetChangeListener = new WOWZPlayerView.PacketThresholdChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void packetsBelowMinimumThreshold(int packetCount) {
                    WOWZLog.debug("Packets have fallen below threshold "+packetCount+"... ");

                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Packets have fallen below threshold ... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void packetsAboveMinimumThreshold(int packetCount) {
                    WOWZLog.debug("Packets have risen above threshold "+packetCount+" ... ");

                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Packets have risen above threshold ... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            mStreamPlayerView.setShowAllNotificationsWhenBelowThreshold(false);
            mStreamPlayerView.setMinimumPacketThreshold(20);
            mStreamPlayerView.registerPacketThresholdListener(packetChangeListener);
            ///// End packet change notification listener

            mTimerView.setTimerProvider(new TimerView.TimerProvider() {
                @Override
                public long getTimecode() {
                    return mStreamPlayerView.getCurrentTime();
                }

                @Override
                public long getDuration() {
                    return mStreamPlayerView.getDuration();
                }
            });

            mSeekVolume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    if (mStreamPlayerView != null && mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying()) {
                        mStreamPlayerView.setVolume(progress);
                    }
                }

                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }
            });

            // listen for volume changes from device buttons, etc.
            mVolumeSettingChangeObserver = new VolumeChangeObserver(this, new Handler());
            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, mVolumeSettingChangeObserver);
            mVolumeSettingChangeObserver.setVolumeChangeListener(new VolumeChangeObserver.VolumeChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVolumeChanged(int previousLevel, int currentLevel) {
                    if (mSeekVolume != null)
                        mSeekVolume.setProgress(currentLevel);

                    if (mStreamPlayerView != null && mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying()) {
                        mStreamPlayerView.setVolume(currentLevel);
                    }
                }
            });

            mBtnScale.setState(mStreamPlayerView.getScaleMode() == WOWZMediaConfig.FILL_VIEW);

            // The streaming player configuration properties
            mStreamPlayerConfig = new WOWZPlayerConfig();

            mBufferingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mBufferingDialog.setTitle(R.string.status_buffering);
            mBufferingDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.msg_please_wait));
            mBufferingDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getResources().getString(R.string.button_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    cancelBuffering(dialogInterface);
                }
            });

            // testing player data event handler.
            mStreamPlayerView.registerDataEventListener("onMetaData", new WOWZDataEvent.EventListener(){
                @Override
                public WOWZDataMap onWZDataEvent(String eventName, WOWZDataMap eventParams) {
                    String meta = "";
                    if(eventParams!=null)
                        meta = eventParams.toString();


                    WOWZLog.debug("onWZDataEvent -> eventName "+eventName+" = "+meta);

                    return null;
                }
            });

            // testing player data event handler.
            mStreamPlayerView.registerDataEventListener("onStatus", new WOWZDataEvent.EventListener(){
                @Override
                public WOWZDataMap onWZDataEvent(String eventName, WOWZDataMap eventParams) {
                    if(eventParams!=null)
                        WOWZLog.debug("onWZDataEvent -> eventName "+eventName+" = "+eventParams.toString());

                    return null;
                }
            });

            // testing player data event handler.
            mStreamPlayerView.registerDataEventListener("onTextData", new WOWZDataEvent.EventListener(){
                @Override
                public WOWZDataMap onWZDataEvent(String eventName, WOWZDataMap eventParams) {
                    if(eventParams!=null)
                        WOWZLog.debug("onWZDataEvent -> "+eventName+" = "+eventParams.get("text"));

                    return null;
                }
            });
        } else {
            mHelp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mStatusView.setErrorMessage(WowzaGoCoder.getLastError().getErrorDescription());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mVolumeSettingChangeObserver != null)
            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(mVolumeSettingChangeObserver);

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * Android Activity class methods
     */

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        syncUIControlState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mStreamPlayerView != null && mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying()) {
            mStreamPlayerView.stop();

            // Wait for the streaming player to disconnect and shutdown...
            mStreamPlayerView.getCurrentStatus().waitForState(WOWZState.IDLE);
        }

        super.onPause();
    }
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    public boolean isPlayerConfigReady()
    {

        return false;
    }

    /*
    Click handler for network pausing
     */
    public void onPauseNetwork(View v)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause_network);
        if(btn.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("pause network")) {
            WOWZLog.info("Pausing network...");
            btn.setText("Unpause Network");
            mStreamPlayerView.pauseNetworkStack();
        }
        else{
            WOWZLog.info("Unpausing network... btn.getText(): "+btn.getText());
            btn.setText("Pause Network");
            mStreamPlayerView.unpauseNetworkStack();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Click handler for the playback button
     */
    public void onTogglePlayStream(View v) {
        if (mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying()) {
            mStreamPlayerView.stop();
        } else if (mStreamPlayerView.isReadyToPlay()) {
            if(!this.isNetworkAvailable()){
                displayErrorDialog("No internet connection, please try again later.");
                return;
            }

//            if(!this.isPlayerConfigReady()){
//                displayErrorDialog("Please be sure to include a host, stream, and application to playback a stream.");
//                return;
//            }

            mHelp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            WOWZStreamingError configValidationError = mStreamPlayerConfig.validateForPlayback();
            if (configValidationError != null) {
                mStatusView.setErrorMessage(configValidationError.getErrorDescription());
            } else {
                // Set the detail level for network logging output
                mStreamPlayerView.setLogLevel(mWZNetworkLogLevel);

                // Set the player's pre-buffer duration as stored in the app prefs
                float preBufferDuration = GoCoderSDKPrefs.getPreBufferDuration(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));

                mStreamPlayerConfig.setPreRollBufferDuration(preBufferDuration);

                // Start playback of the live stream
                mStreamPlayerView.play(mStreamPlayerConfig, this);
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * WOWZStatusCallback interface methods
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized void onWZStatus(WOWZStatus status) {
        final WOWZStatus playerStatus = new WOWZStatus(status);

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                WOWZStatus status = new WOWZStatus(playerStatus.getState());
                switch(playerStatus.getState()) {

                    case WOWZPlayerView.STATE_PLAYING:
                        // Keep the screen on while we are playing back the stream
                        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                        if (mStreamPlayerConfig.getPreRollBufferDuration() == 0f) {
                            mTimerView.startTimer();
                        }

                        // Since we have successfully opened up the server connection, store the connection info for auto complete

                        GoCoderSDKPrefs.storeHostConfig(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PlayerActivity.this), mStreamPlayerConfig);

                        // Log the stream metadata
                        WOWZLog.debug(TAG, "Stream metadata:\n" + mStreamPlayerView.getMetadata());
                        break;

                    case WOWZPlayerView.STATE_READY_TO_PLAY:
                        // Clear the "keep screen on" flag
                        WOWZLog.debug(TAG, "STATE_READY_TO_PLAY player activity status!");
                        if(playerStatus.getLastError()!=null)
                            displayErrorDialog(playerStatus.getLastError());

                        playerStatus.clearLastError();
                        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                        mTimerView.stopTimer();

                        break;

                    case WOWZPlayerView.STATE_PREBUFFERING_STARTED:
                        WOWZLog.debug(TAG, "Dialog for buffering should show...");
                        showBuffering();
                        break;

                    case WOWZPlayerView.STATE_PREBUFFERING_ENDED:
                        WOWZLog.debug(TAG, "Dialog for buffering should stop...");
                        hideBuffering();
                        // Make sure player wasn't signaled to shutdown
                        if (mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying()) {
                            mTimerView.startTimer();
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                syncUIControlState();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onWZError(final WOWZStatus playerStatus) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                displayErrorDialog(playerStatus.getLastError());
                syncUIControlState();
            }
        });
    }


    public void onToggleMute(View v) {
        mBtnMic.toggleState();

        if (mStreamPlayerView != null)
            mStreamPlayerView.mute(!mBtnMic.isOn());

        mSeekVolume.setEnabled(mBtnMic.isOn());
    }

    public void onToggleScaleMode(View v) {
        int newScaleMode = mStreamPlayerView.getScaleMode() == WOWZMediaConfig.RESIZE_TO_ASPECT ? WOWZMediaConfig.FILL_VIEW : WOWZMediaConfig.RESIZE_TO_ASPECT;
        mBtnScale.setState(newScaleMode == WOWZMediaConfig.FILL_VIEW);
        mStreamPlayerView.setScaleMode(newScaleMode);
    }


    public void onStreamMetadata(View v) {
        WOWZDataMap streamMetadata = mStreamPlayerView.getMetadata();
        WOWZDataMap streamStats = mStreamPlayerView.getStreamStats();
//        WOWZDataMap streamConfig = mStreamPlayerView.getStreamConfig().toDataMap();
        WOWZDataMap streamConfig = new WOWZDataMap();
        WOWZDataMap streamInfo = new WOWZDataMap();

        streamInfo.put("- Stream Statistics -", streamStats);
        streamInfo.put("- Stream Metadata -", streamMetadata);
        //streamInfo.put("- Stream Configuration -", streamConfig);

        DataTableFragment dataTableFragment = DataTableFragment.newInstance("Stream Information", streamInfo, false, false);


        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, dataTableFragment)
                .addToBackStack("metadata_fragment")
                .commit();
    }


    public void onSettings(View v) {
        // Display the prefs fragment
        GoCoderSDKPrefs.PrefsFragment prefsFragment = new GoCoderSDKPrefs.PrefsFragment();
        prefsFragment.setFixedSource(true);
        prefsFragment.setForPlayback(true);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, prefsFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }


    private void syncUIControlState() {
        boolean disableControls = (!(mStreamPlayerView.isReadyToPlay() || mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying()) || sGoCoderSDK == null);
        if (disableControls) {
            mBtnPlayStream.setEnabled(false);
            mBtnSettings.setEnabled(false);
            mSeekVolume.setEnabled(false);
            mBtnScale.setEnabled(false);
            mBtnMic.setEnabled(false);
            mStreamMetadata.setEnabled(false);
       } else {
            mBtnPlayStream.setState(mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying());
            mBtnPlayStream.setEnabled(true);

            if (mStreamPlayerConfig.isAudioEnabled()) {
                mBtnMic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mBtnMic.setEnabled(true);

                mSeekVolume.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mSeekVolume.setEnabled(mBtnMic.isOn());
                mSeekVolume.setProgress(mStreamPlayerView.getVolume());
            } else {
                mSeekVolume.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mBtnMic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            mBtnScale.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mBtnScale.setVisibility(mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying() && mStreamPlayerConfig.isVideoEnabled() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mBtnScale.setEnabled(mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying() && mStreamPlayerConfig.isVideoEnabled());

            mBtnSettings.setEnabled(!mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying());
            mBtnSettings.setVisibility(mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

            mStreamMetadata.setEnabled(mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying());
            mStreamMetadata.setVisibility(mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void showBuffering() {
        try {
            if (mBufferingDialog == null) return;
            mBufferingDialog.show();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }

    private void cancelBuffering(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        if(mStreamPlayerConfig.getHLSBackupURL()!=null || mStreamPlayerConfig.isHLSEnabled()){
            mStreamPlayerView.stop(true);
        }
        else if (mStreamPlayerView != null && mStreamPlayerView.isPlaying()) {
            mStreamPlayerView.stop(true);
        }
    }

    private void hideBuffering() {
        if (mBufferingDialog.isShowing())
            mBufferingDialog.dismiss();
    }

   @Override
    public void syncPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        mWZNetworkLogLevel = Integer.valueOf(prefs.getString("wz_debug_net_log_level", String.valueOf(WOWZLog.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG)));

        mStreamPlayerConfig.setIsPlayback(true);
        if (mStreamPlayerConfig != null)
            GoCoderSDKPrefs.updateConfigFromPrefsForPlayer(prefs, mStreamPlayerConfig);
    }

    private class StatusCallback implements WOWZStatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void onWZStatus(WOWZStatus wzStatus) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onWZError(WOWZStatus wzStatus) {
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is;

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.sampleapp/com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.sampleapp.PlayerActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid surface: null
```

Comment: Did you got issue like, While Live Streaming if user goes in background and come back to foreground Live Streaming is not working on Viewer end with Wowza WOWZPlayerView?

Answer (score 0):

You start the stream in onCreate. At this time the Surface used by WOWZPlayerView is not ready yet and the app crashes with the 'Invalid surface' error.
If you look at the sample test in the GoCoder SDK, the playback is started when the user clicks a button. Eg. when the Surface is valid.
Create a button and move your 'mStreamPlayerView.play(mStreamPlayerConfig, statusCallback);' to the button.onClick.
Or ... use any GoCoder SDK v1.7 and more recent.
Please, let me know if I can help any further.
Thanks